# A problem of subgroup of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ be a finite group of order $pq$ where $p$ & $q$ are prime numbers such that $p>q$. Prove that $G$ has at most one subgroup of order $p$.Hence prove that a group of order 6 has at most one subgroup of order 3.

My try is that i let $G$ has two subgroup $H$ & $K$ of same order $p$.Then we have to prove $H=K$

since $p>q$ & $o(G)=pq$ & clearly $p>\sqrt{pq}$

hence $o(H)>\sqrt{o(G)}$ & also $o(K)>\sqrt{o(G)}$

so there must some elements in intersection of both of the subgroups with identity i.e

## $H\cap K$$\neq ${e}

now since o($H\cap K$) must divide $o(H)$ & $o(G)$.And from above conclusion $o(H\cap K)\neq 1$ & $p$ is prime so $o(H\cap K)$ must be $p$ hence

$H=K$

but i am not sure about the line which is 'bold'.
plz suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, though you have not explained that.

To do that, consider the map $H\times K\to G$ defined as $(h,k)\mapsto hk$. What can you say about it if $H\cap K=\{e\}$?

Comment: then o(HK)=o(H)o(K)=9 but according to mapping o(HK)=o(G)=6 hence it is not possible.I hope this is not a stupid logic.

Comment: Yes, but the point is, the mapping must be injective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_{1}$ be the subgroup generated by $g_{1}$, $H_{2}$ be the subgroup generated by $g_{2}$. Assuming for the moment that $H_{1}\not=H_{2}$ and $|H_{1}|=|H_{2}|=p$. Then $g_{2}$ cannot be $g_{1}^{i}$ for any $i$. Then the subgroup generated by $ g_{1},g_{2}$ has order at least $p^{2}$ since all pairs $g_{1}^{i}g_{2}^{j}\not=g_{1}^{k}g_{2}^{l}$, if $(i,j)\not=(k,l)$. Otherwise we have an contradiction after factoring out identical terms. But we know $G$ has order $pq$ only, and $pq<p^{2}$ strictly. So $H_{1}$ must be equal to $H_{2}$.

You may also try Swlow's theorem to solve this problem.